# Compare a value from one dataframe column to values in the other columns from the same df?

Tags: python, pandas

Not a native english speaker,
I have got a df. Lets say in df 'a' column get 'apple' compare to other 'apple' in c column and make a combined df.

Compare value(apple) from column 'a' and compare it with the same value (apple) in 'c' column and make a combined df

df

```
                        a        b        c

                0       9        11       values

                1      apple     10       testcase

                2       8         8       apple

                3       7         7       apple

                4       6         6       test

                5       5         5       items
```

resultant_df

```
                        a         b        c

                0      apple     10       testcase

                1       8         8       apple

                2       7         7       apple
```

I tried to compare and get one value, but couldn't get all values.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: compare value(apple) from column 'a' and compare it with the same value (apple) in 'c' column and make a combined df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
resultant_df=df[df[['a','c']].eq('apple').any(axis=1)]
resultant_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
print(resultant_df)

       a   b         c
0  apple  10  testcase
1      8   8     apple
2      7   7     apple
```

---

Explanation: with `df[['a','c']].eq('apple').any(axis=1)` you get a Serie with True value in those rows that contain `apple`. `Reset_index` is simply used to reset the index to 0,1,2 ...

```
df[['a','c']].eq('apple').any(axis=1)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

---

If you also had to take into account `'apple'` in all the columns then you would use:

```
df.eq('apple').any(axis=1)
```